# tmux: always show session's windows list on left

Tags: tmux

I would like tmux to always show a list of the session's windows on the left.

When I click once on a window in the list, it should switch to that window on the right side (no preview - switch straight to it), and also switch focus to that window, but still keep the windows list open on the left with its line for the switched-to window now highlighted. The result would look similar to what [mprocs provides](https://github.com/pvolok/mprocs?tab=readme-ov-file#screenshots).

I thought the [`choose-tree`](https://man.openbsd.org/OpenBSD-current/man1/tmux.1#choose-tree) command might help, perhaps with a custom template. Normally `choose-tree` goes away after the user chooses a window, so maybe it would have to re-run after the user's choice (maybe in a 'while' loop).

How should I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Create three sessions:

- `menu`
- `windows`
- `main`, containing one window split horizontally into two panes running clients attached to the `menu` and `windows` sessions respectively.

In `menu`, run `choose-tree` in a loop with:

- a filter that only shows windows from the `windows` session, and
- a template that calls `select-window`:

```
while true; do
  tmux choose-tree -f '#{==:windows,#{session_name}}' \
    'select-window -t %%; select-pane -t main:0.1'
done
```

Attach to the main session.

To-do:

- The selected window in `menu` jumps back to the top after selecting a window.
- Window selection in `menu` requires a double-click instead of one click.
- `menu` shows the `windows` session at the top (we just want a list of windows, not a tree).
- <s>`menu` does not auto-update when a new window is created in the `windows` session.</s> It does, but with a delay.
- `menu` does not auto-resize to the width of the longest window name.
- `menu` does not have a 'new window' right-click menu entry.